# Burninate / clean the [qlikview.next] tag

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, burninate-request

**Bit of background**: QlikView.next was the working name for a project launched by Qlik Corporation to create a new suite of BI tools, and a product named "Qlik Sense" was a direct result of this project.

As such, QlikView.next is not actually a product that you can use or program with, but rather it is just an old project name.

**The proposal**:Currently the [qlikview.next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlikview.next) currently has 16 questions, however, all of those questions also have "companion" tags of [qlikview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlikview) and/or [qliksense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qliksense). The tag also does not have a tag wiki.

I am quite active in the [qlikview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlikview) tag and as one of my first editing tasks (hopefully I've followed the rules by asking on Meta first!), would like to clean up this tag from these questions and then remove this tag.

Comment: There's only 16 tags. Let 'er rip.  Be sure to clean up those questions otherwise though; don't just delete the tags.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you. I was planning to clean them too, however, rene beat me to removing the tags, however, this means I can't remember which questions used to have that tag - any idea how to obtain a list?

Answer (score 2):

I removed the tag from those 16 questions. The tag itself will be removed when the clean-up script runs at 03:00 UTC